# How i change the layout of search page in Magento Go

Tags: search, magento, layout

In "Magento go" My search page is displaying in 2-column with right bar, but i want search page in 1 column.

Answer (score 2):

> **Please Ignore for Magento Go** I added this answer that is not actually applicable to Magento Go. Apologies - left here in case someone wants to do this on a Magento CE install. Leave a comment if you'd rather I delete it.

I'm not sure if it's the same in Magento Go. But in Magento CE you would change the layout file `catalogsearch.xml` and change

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <label>Quick Search Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

to

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <label>Quick Search Form</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Comment: in magento go no file structure is accessible so you can not put code like this